# Binding FocusedElement in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: binding, focusmanager

I am trying to focus a control within a HierarchicalDataTemplate.  Unfortunately, my attempt to bind to a control within the template is failing.  Here is my code:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeView_Experiment:BookmarkPage}">
            <DockPanel>
                <ToggleButton ... edited for brevity ... />
                <Controls:EditableTextBlock x:Name="EditBox" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEditable="True" Focusable="True"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsFocused, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}" Value="true">
                    <!-- The Value binding fails with the error: Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=EditBox -->
                    <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=EditBox}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The trigger fires when the treeview item gets the focus, but the {Binding ElementName=EditBox} fails with the message "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=EditBox,..."

How can I fix this binding?  Or is there a better way to set the focus of a control within a HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding this ugly little bit of code behind. Attach this to the treeview's onselection changed:

```
    private void SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var treeView = sender as TreeView;

        var selectedContainer =
            typeof (TreeView).GetProperty("SelectedContainer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).
                GetValue(treeView, null) as TreeViewItem;

        // Find the element we want to focus.
        var focusControl = selectedContainer.FindVisualChild<TextBox>();
        if (focusControl != null)
            focusControl.Focus();
    }
```

The following extension method is required:

```
    public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        var childCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }

            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
            {
                return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at the TreeView and trying to find the item to focus, it may be better to have the TreeViewItem itself do the focusing.